# Adding images or videos to iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I am trying to use `UIImagePickerController` with `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`, but it says, "No photos". Where does the simulator get the images from? Where should I copy the images so that they are displayed in the simulator?

Comment: Drag images to the iPhone simulator. Then right-click on the image to save it.

Comment: I couldn't right click it with the current sim but I could click the "Share" icon and then save the image.

Comment: Scott Rowley's response worked for me, and Joe Blow's didn't. I think this might be a Xcode 5.1.1 release difference.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

The simplest way to get images, videos, etc onto the simulator is to drag and drop them from your computer onto the simulator. This will cause the Simulator to open the Photos app and start populating the library.

---

If you want a scriptable method, read on.

Note - while this is valid, and works, I think [Koen's solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35271607/18017) is now a better one, since it does not require rebooting the simulator.

Identify your simulator by going to xCode->Devices, selecting your simulator, and checking the Identifier value. Or you can ensure the simulator is running and run the following to get the device ID `xcrun simctl list | grep Booted`

Go to

~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[Simulator Identifier]/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE

and add IMG_nnnn.THM and IMG_nnnn.JPG. You will then need to reset your simulator (Hardware->Reboot) to allow it to notice the new changes. It doesn't matter if they are not JPEGs - they can both be PNGs, but it appears that both of them must be present for it to work. You may need to create DCIM if it doesn't already exist, and in that case you should start nnnn from 0001. The JPG files are the fullsize version, while the THM files are the thumbnail, and are 75x75 pixels in size. I wrote a script to do this, but there's a better documented one over [here](http://ofcodeandmen.poltras.com/2008/11/04/adding-pictures-to-the-simulator/)(-link no longer work).

You can also add photos from safari in the simulator, by Tapping and Holding on the image. If you drag an image (or any other file, like a PDF) to the simulator, it will immediately open Safari and display the image, so this is quite an easy way of getting images to it.

Comment: Under iPhone SDK 3.0, this has changed just a bit.  Now, the thumbnail files (".THM") need to go under 100APPLE/.MISC.  Otherwise, all the photos will appear as black boxes.

Comment: How do I update the icon on the Saved Photos cell in the main Photo Album table view?

Comment: My location is at `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.1.3/Media/DCIM/100APPLE`

Comment: how do you get the .thm files from images coming from an iPhone?

Comment: Note: You can also add videos to the simulator using this method as well.

Comment: I didn't see the folder named 100APPLE, so I made one. Still didn't work.

Comment: For me with the 5.1 simulator, you don't need the .THM files and the directory needed to be ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE The script link in the answer was no longer working for me so I whipped up my own script here: https://gist.github.com/3738695

Comment: Unfortunately with iOS6, this technique no longer works. This little importing app which you can run in the simulator works well though - http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/09/importing-photos/ See the lower rated answers below this one.

Comment: This answer should be unaccepted as it doesn't work with newer iOS environments. The simplest solution is mine below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41884742/2813408

Comment: Hardly. The answer needs a path change to continue to work, and the correct thing to do is edit the existing answer to modify the path. Your answer is a completely different approach, and only simpler if you hate the command line.

Comment: "You can also add photos from safari in the simulator, by Tapping and Holding on the image. If you drag an image (or any other file, like a PDF) to the simulator, it will immediately open Safari and display the image, so this is quite an easy way of getting images to it." Awesome, thanks!

Comment: "You will then need to reset your simulator " -- Since `Simulater > Reset Content and Settings` is not meant here, maybe reword?

Comment: Anyway, [it's a lot simpler nowadays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25758880/539599).

Comment: If anyone is looking for which simulator has which UDID check the path ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/device_set.plist

Comment: For drag and drop operation, it is important to know that some directories has no read / write access for example "Downloads". So dragging from downloads and dropping onto simulator throws an error.

Answer (score 456):

Explain step by step of Airsource Ltd's answer for adding image to simulator:

1. Drag it to simulator, then Safari opens
   (or browse to the Image in the internet using Safari)
2. Hold your click on the image
3. When the pop-up appears, choose Save Image and enjoy ;)

Update: for iOS Simulator 4.2, do these steps twice to get it work. Thanks `kevboh`!

Update: This also works for iOS Simulator 6.1

Comment: This doesn't work for me with iOS simulator Version 4.2 (235).  I can run through steps 1-3 fine, but when I go to "Photos" I don't see anything.

Comment: This worked for me when I had no apps open, when I had an app open it went through the same steps but didn't actually work.

Comment: image format should be .jpg only..it would not work for .png i think

Comment: Wow this was so easy it felt like I was cheating! BTW as noted by @KarenAnne, this works in iOS 6.0 simulator, with photos ending up in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Media/DCIM/100APPLE and (it appears) no .THM files.  In any case, great tip!

Comment: Works perfectly with iOS7 as well. Nice answer.

Comment: this should really be the accepted answer. screw messin' around with the file system.

Comment: Not working for me in iOS7 simulator - the solution relies on Safari to work, and Safari is not present in the iOS7 simulator.

Comment: @Ash I just checked and Safari is available in the iOS 7 simulator.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 6 and Safari is no longer involved. Images go directly into the photo library.

Comment: ThomasW, I can't check why I didn't have Safari in my simulator because I no longer have the same computer, but I believe it may have been missing due to having upgraded my Xcode from an older version. In any case, I recall at the time that the Safari icon itself was missing. Maybe a later update fixed the problem? My comment is almost a year old.

Comment: Still works in iOS 17 :-)

Comment: I get a popup: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1.)"

Answer (score 131):

3 Simple Steps

1. Drag & Drop image onto simulator
       - this will open a browser with your image
2. Click & hold image
       - this will open options
3. save image
       - this will copy image onto simulator

[Watch YouTube Video ( add images to iphone simulator)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NqHnYGNAp8)

Comment: Doesn't work for video. Because nothing happen when you long press the screen.

Comment: I get a popup: The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1.)

Answer (score 64):

With iOS 8.0, we added the ability to just drag and drop images into the iOS Simulator.  You can drag a bunch of images into the window, and they should be imported into the photo reel for that simulated device.  You can also do this with the simctl command line tool. 'xcrun simctl addphoto  '

Comment: Thanks! Great feature. Note that you can't drag them to the Dock icon, you have to drag them into the Simulator window. Hope that's changed soon to allow dragging to the icon.

Comment: Dragging to the Dock icon should bring the app windows to the foreground (like if you drag to the Finder dock icon).

Comment: Hi @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia! Two questions: the command only works for pictures, not videos, right? Also, is there any way to input "moment"-style information to the simulator (i.e., create multiple moments, possibly backdated, etc.)?

Comment: Correct.  It is just for adding photos.  It cannot be used for videos.  I'm not aware of a way to backdate the events, but that may be possible through the Photos app.  If not, it would certainly be worth filing a radar for at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia, It doesn't preserve the original metadata of the assets. Please have a look at my project that helps you import your assets while preserving all the metadata (Including videos!) https://github.com/matibot/MBAssetsImporter

Comment: @MatiBot Please give Xcode 7 a try.  Metadata should be preserved when importing in Xcode 7.

Comment: Yes, it certainly is ;)  BTW, Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com requesting video import as well.

Comment: Looks like there's 'xcrun simctl addvideo' now! This is great!

Comment: FYI: I added Live Photo importing to Xcode 8.3. Now dragging the photo and video for a Live Photo into the Simulator window (or using the new simctl addmedia command) they should import as a Live Photo, not as separate photo and videos.

Comment: Works with Xcode 10. Please note: it does not work with multiple images, you have to drag one at a time.

Answer (score 53):

Since Xcode 6 you can use the command line tool `xcrun simctl`.

Usage is very simple; to add a photo to the currently running simulator you use the `booted` placeholder.

```
xcrun simctl addmedia booted ./MyFile.jpg
```

To add it to any other simulator, you use its device id, which can be found by running `xcrun simctl list`.

```
xcrun simctl addmedia E201E636-CE6C-11E5-AB30-625662870761 ./MyFile.jpg
```

Comment: The last command "xcrun simctl addmedia E201E636-CE6C-11E5-AB30-625662870761 ./MyFile.jpg" only seem to work if the simulator is running. I was hoping there would be a solution to add images without running i.e. to prepare before running a simulator.

Answer (score 27):

Its simple. Just follow these steps :

1. Drag and drop image onto Simulator
2. Now image opens into Safari browser (file://.../ImageName). Tap-and-hold on the Image.
3. This displays actionSheet with Save, Cancel option (Also copy in case of iOS 7 simulator).

   [image: Screenshot for Actionsheet]
4. Save the image. The image gets added into Library.

   [image: Photo Library]

Answer (score 23):

I just stumbled upon how to **bulk** upload images on the iOS Simulator. (I've only confirmed it on 6.1.)

1. Backup the folder:

   ```
   ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Media
   ```
2. Copy all your images into the folder:

   ```
   ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
   ```
3. **Move or delete the folder:**

   ```
   ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Media/PhotoData
   ```
4. Restart iOS Simulator
5. Open the *Photos* app

The simulator will restore all the images from the 100APPLE folder!

Comment: Excellent solution. I had dropped my photos in the Media/DCIM folder but I needed to also delete the PhotoData folder. And, this works for me with iOS 7 too.

Comment: Of the four methods I've tried under iOS7.0.3 4-inch simulator, this is the only one that worked, although I did find I got duplicates of every image. Upvoted.

Comment: I was able to use this github project under iOS7.0 to import the images https://github.com/basilhe/iOS-Simulator-Photo-Importer. Seems to be a variant of the photo importer mentioned before, but also does videos.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why the photos I've transferred is not showing even if I already placed them in Media/DCIM/100APPLE. Turns out, there is an extra step of deleting Media/PhotoData folder.

Comment: Yah, although I got duplicate images.. :O

Comment: Read below user @user2966386's answer. Simpler and will not cause duplicates. :)

Answer (score 21):

For iOS 7 I did the following:

copy photos to these two folders:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
```

delete these 4 files only (to avoid duplicates on relaunch):

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite-shm
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite-wal
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite-shm
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite-wal
```

Comment: Deleting the `*.sqlite-` files worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, it really helped me. I tried several methods and till now I was doing drag and drop. But it is more easier way when you need to copy too many images :)

Comment: With iOS 8, you can now drag photos onto the simulator :)

Comment: Unlike Arel's answer, movies moved into DCIM/100APPLE will not become available with this technique.

Answer (score 18):

Just drag images to the iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 18):

If you can not drag and drop your files because you experience the error:

**One or more media items failed to import: : The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1.)**

Move your files into the `Documents` folder and then drag them into the simulator. This will trigger the simulator to ask for permissions to access your files. Having them inside the `Downloads` folder, will not.

Comment: thank you lol the documents folder was the key here

Comment: Thank you so much!  This saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Also, it didn't work for my `~/Desktop` folder for some reason... Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

This is MUCH easier with the new iOS Simulator that comes with Xcode 6+ (iOS Simulator 8.1 and above.)  Now all you have to do is drag *one or more* photos onto the iOS Simulator window, and instead of opening Safari, the Photos app opens, and instantly adds *all* dragged-in photos to the device.

Answer (score 12):

**Method 1 (Easiest Way):  If you have your image on Mac**

You can drag an image from the Finder on your Mac to Simulator, and it is saved to the Saved Photos album.

**Method 2: If its on any URL**

To save an image from a webpage to the Photos app

1. Place the pointer on the image you want to save, and hold down the mouse button or trackpad.
2. When the menu appears, click Save Image to save the image to the Photos app in an iOS simulator.
3. The image is saved to the Saved Photos album in the Photos app.

Incase someone looking for [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwithiOSandwatchOS/InteractingwithiOSandwatchOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH8-SW11) regarding Copying and Pasting in Simulator.
[image: Save Image from Safari]

Comment: The only drawbacks is that it doesn't work with multiple images at once.

Comment: Works with multiple images fine. Can't believe I didn't know this sooner.

Answer (score 9):

None of the answers had the exact solution that I needed.

The steps I've found for myself working on iOS 5.0 and above simulator are as follows:

1. Close the simulator if it is running xcode project.
2. Run simulator from the dock by clicking on it.
3. Drag & drop the image into simulator.
4. Tap and hold the image (opened in safari) and select the save option.

You are done.

Comment: The images end out thumbnailed to 552x668 resolution, which isn't the original image. In contrast, the image importer preserves the original image resolution.

Answer (score 7):

For iOS 5.1 this is further changed to new path

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE

Answer (score 7):

As of iOS 8, you can just drag all your photos onto the simulator window and they'll save to camera roll automatically. You can do as many at a time as you want.

Comment: This was super delightful to find out today, especially for testing performance of collection views with a huge amount of image data + NSCache optimization.

Comment: This has stopped working on XCode 10 (tested on 10.1), iOS 12.1 :(

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers above worked for me on iOS 15.

I simply opened Files app and dragged and dropped the image there. It automatically imported the image to the Photos app and I was able to use everywhere through my simulator.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

If you need to import more than just one or two photos then take a look at this [article](http://aptogo.co.uk/?p=203) that I wrote. It describes an easy way to perform a bulk import of photos and works for iOS 4.x.

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed to make a simple change to the app: Because I'm running the 4.2 simulator and this was designed to run on 4.0 (which I don't have), I went to "Project" -> "Edit Project Settings" and then under "Architectures" I changed the "Base SDK" to "Latest iOS".

Answer (score 6):

For iOS 8, If there is no need to retain photo capture date and location, just drop photo files to the simulator.

To retain photo meta data, do the following:

1. Copy photo files to: /Users/{USER}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{UDID}/data/Media/DCIM/100Apple
2. Remove (or rename) folder: /Users/{USER}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{UDID}/data/Media/photoData
3. Relaunch Simulator

Note: You need to replace {USER} with your user name and {UDID} with the UDID of the simulator. To find UDID for your simulator, from Terminal, run 'xcrun simctl list'.

Comment: Does not make a difference in IOS 8.1

Answer (score 4):

In OS X Catalina with Xcode 11 you have to do this differently.

First you MUST start the simulator.  If you want to copy, say a photo to MULTIPLE simulated devices.  Start all of them up.  Then Right Click on a SINGLE (Multiple images will fail.  ONLY does a single file.).

Share -> Simulator

A 'share sheet will pop-up.  You must choose an active simulator in the combo box and hit send.

It will send one to many but NOT many to many of selected photos.

I hope this helps folks.  Drag and drop was supported in the last versions of Xcode and OS X but not with OS X Catalina and Xcode 11.

While this IS in the directions it currently IS NOT working.

What DID work for me was to first import my images into iPhoto on OS X and then DRAG/DROP them from my OS X iPhoto and drop into the simulator.  It would appear the drag/drop for photos into the simulator is CURRENTLY only working from OS X iPhoto.  :-(

Answer (score 3):

```
quit the simulator.

Run simulator from the dock by clicking on it.

Drag & drop the image into simulator which you want to add.

it will open image in safari .

tap and hold the image and click the save option.

then open gallery and you will see the image which u had saved recently.
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding an image to the Iphone Simulation running IOS 8.0 is even easier.

- Drag your image to the simulator
- IOS opens the Photo app and your image is now part of your collection.

No need to deal with Safari anymore

Comment: You can now also drag, in one go, multiple photos straight into the Camera Roll album.

Comment: @PaulArdeleanu, you are right. However, it doesn't preserve you original metadata of the assets. Please have a look at my projects that helps you import your assets while preserving all the metadata https://github.com/matibot/MBAssetsImporter

Comment: @MatiBot, MBAssetsImporter is great for bulk transfer of images - thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 4.2 I had to go and create the 100APPLE folder and restart the simulator, then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

try this app I've made. download the code and run it in simulator https://github.com/cristianbica/CBSimulatorSeed

Comment: Doesn't work out-of-the-box under iOS7 - says something about cocoaPods being out of sync.

Comment: Well you must run pod install to install the pods as they are not in the repo. I've updated the README

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 8.0,the answer is out of date.I found the media resource in the following path:
**~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DeviceID]/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE**

Answer (score 2):

1. Using your pc just Send the image via your email
2. Open the IOS-Simulator then open the email and download the image
3. just click and hold the mouse on the image, and from the options that will be displayed[image]
4. Then, it will be automatically saved to your iOS-Simulator's photo gallery

Comment: This approach works for Big Sur if you get the following error while trying to drag and drop a photo onto the simulator: The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1.)

Answer (score 1):

Just Drag and Drop image into iphone simulator. browser will open to show your image.
press on image until you not receive options to save Image. then Save image.
thats it :). you will see your image in to Photo app in your simulator....

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a bash script to do this.
Check the link[1]

```
#!/bin/bash

# Imports pictures into all iOS simulators.

path_to_pic="src/ios/pictures/"

mkdir -p /Users/$(whoami)/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/{5.0,5.1,6.0,6.1}/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/ -type d -name '100APPLE' -exec cp /Users/$(whoami)/$path_to_pic/* {} \;
```

[1] : https://gist.github.com/firesofmay/5194901

Answer (score 1):

Just to tell you : KONG's solution also works on iOS 7 beta.

His solution was:

Drag the image to simulator, then Safari opens (or browse to the Image in the internet using Safari)
Hold your click on the image
When the pop-up appears, choose Save Image and enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just needed some random images for testing, so this is how I did it.

I have the simplest solution in the world. Just open Safari in the simulator, go to Google images (or your own web or Dropbox URL), view an image, hold down the mouse button for 2 seconds, and you'll see "Save Image" - it will save right into the Photos library. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

an even easier way, is :
open safari on simulator > tap www.google.com
search for random photos "nature"
open each image, press on it  and save it.

Answer (score 1):

With the drag and drop feature you will lose all the metadata of the photos.

I've created a project that make it really easy to import assets to the simulator: [MBAssetsImporter](http://github.com/matibot/MBAssetsImporter).

It enables you to import both videos and photos while preserving all the original metadata of the files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**1. CD to this path:**

> /Users/[macOS user]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[Simulator
>   Identifier]/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
>
> [Simulator Identifier] or UDID can be found at : Hardware => device => manage devices.
>
> eg. cd /Users/rnDeveloper/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7508171A-DC5D-47CF-9BE1-FF950326E3DB/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE

**2. Download photo by run this command:**

> curl -o pic_001.jpg
>   "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/474x/49/25/7a/49257a4b3287b7841922ecdff855fd80.jpg"

**3. Restart your simulator to see the new files.**

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to simply sign into iCloud on the simulator then use that to transfer any files in the drive, including photos.

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 11 and Xcode 9, just drag and drop photos to the Simulator. It will automatically import them in the Library app. Very easy!

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the device is running.
2. Execute the following in terminal:

`open ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$(xcrun simctl list | grep Booted | grep -Eo '[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*')/data/Media/DCIM`

Further regex ref @ https://regex101.com/r/tY951n/3