# Sync image from iTunes to the iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, itunes, synchronization, simulator

I want to know how to sync images from iTunes to the iPhone simulator.

Comment: Maybe you should expand a bit more.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250199/how-do-i-add-photos-to-the-iphone-simulator-for-osx

Comment: Me too - when using the iPad simulator you only get to see what the Safari, Contact and Settings Apps  look like - but the Photos App is also there, but not populated with any photo content....and in order to see what it will look like, the app says that you can synch the iPad simulator with your photos in iTunes.

Trouble is, I'm not sure how to do this. Anyone succeeded in doing this?

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me with iOS4: at the simulator, click home, then click the Photos icon.  Drag the image from your Mac onto the simulator screen.  Then follow the instructions above: hold down the mouse click on the image until the popover comes up.  Choose Save image.  Verify by clicking back to Photos (on the simulator) and inspecting (the new) album "Saved Photos."

Answer (score 7):

I spent a while looking into this, and my conclusion for now is that although the Photos app says:

> "You can sync photos and videos onto
>   your iPad Simulator using iTunes."

it's probably not actually simulator-specific instructions, but a generic message of the form

> "You can sync photos and videos onto
>   your `{DEVICE_NAME}` using iTunes."

Where `{DEVICE_NAME}` is determined by calling `[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]`.

Answer (score 5):

Drag the photo into the simulator. After the iPad Simulator opens the dragged-in image in Safari, press-and-hold the image until the popover comes up. From the popover, choose Save Image. This saves the image to your iPad Simulator photo library.

Answer (score 2):

After the iPad Simulator opens the dragged-in image in Safari, press-and-hold the image until the popover comes up. From the popover, choose Save Image. This saves the image to your iPad Simulator photo library.

Answer (score 2):

- Open Photo Album in the iphone
  simulator
- Drag the image into it IT shall open the image in the browser
- keep right click pressed on the image
- an option with the "save image" shall appear
- click on it And Viola.. you have it inside the Photo Album

Answer (score 2):

If you need to import more than just one or two photos then take a look at this [article](http://aptogo.co.uk/?p=203). It describes an easy way to perform a bulk import of photos.

Answer (score 0):

I'VE GOT IT! You must 'drag' the picture to the ipad simulator.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately for people who regularly upgrade, the iPhone Simulator for iOS 4 does not have a Photo Album as far as I can see. None of the suggestions above works with it.