# how to load the photos and videos to Iphone Simulator 4.0

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to load the photos and videos into the IPhone Simulator 4.0.

Best Regards,
Mohammed Sadiq.

Comment: Unless the iPhone OS 4.0 Simulator is different than the rest, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468879/adding-images-to-iphone-simulator , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250199/how-do-i-add-photos-to-the-iphone-simulator-for-osx , and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287622/how-to-push-video-on-iphone-simulator

Comment: It does appear to have changed in iOS 4.0. I'm having trouble with this too.

Answer (score 19):

The trick is:

- Quit the simulator
- Use the Finder to add photos to the .../iPhone Simulator/4.0.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE folder
- Delete the /iPhone Simulator/4.0.1/Media/PhotoData folder
- Re-launch the simulator and open Photos. It should rebuild your photo index from the contents of the DCIM folder.

Comment: It does works for both i.e. videos and images. Besides, works on iOS 6.1 too.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the photos from Safari still works on iPhone Simulator 4.0, though has some glitches. Maybe something like you need not to hurry to make sure that Safari saves the photo, etc.

Also it looks like there is slight delay before Photos updates the list of photos available.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to import more than just one or two photos then take a look at this [article](http://aptogo.co.uk/?p=203) that I wrote. It describes an easy way to perform a bulk import of photos and works for iOS 4.x.