# regarding iTunes & iPhone simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, itunes

I want to know how I can synchronize images, music & videos through iTunes to the iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 1):

If you search this forum you'll find more than one discussion about this. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250199/how-do-i-add-photos-to-the-iphone-simulator-for-osx) is probably the most comprehensive.

Ultimately, all your media is stored in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Media. There does not seem to be a way of syncing from iTunes, but various people have written scripts to transfer the files.

Comment: i added videos there already in that path what you u provide in your answer. but my image picker viewer unable to pick b'coz it shows no videos , now i want that the videos will be show in my iphone simulator in photolibrary

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Sorry.