# How can I add some photos to the simulator photo library?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, photolibrary

How can I add some photos to the simulator photo library?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468879/adding-images-to-iphone-simulator AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250199/how-do-i-add-photos-to-the-iphone-simulator-for-osx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open safari in simulator .. search for any type of images (.jpg images, .png etc.), later finding the image give a long press on that image for few seconds .. an action window will open with these buttons inside it Save Image, Copy, Cancel. Press save, then the images will be saved into the Photos Library.

Answer (score 2):

Use simulators web browser to find some pictures and save them.