# Adding images to iPhone Simulator Photo Albums - Accepted "tricks" not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I've tried every trick that I've read about, including [answers here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468879/adding-images-to-iphone-simulator) to no avail.

1. Adding photos to the correct directory in Application Support
2. Save images from safari - both locally and from the web

For #1, here's what I have

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0000.JPG
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/.MISC/IMG_0000.THM
```

They are both actual jpeg files. In fact, they're both the copies of the exact same file.

- Max OSX 10.7.1
- iOS Simulator 4.3 (238.2)
- Xcode 4.1 build 4B110

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to use the latest Xcode build (4D199)? Any message in the Console when you try to save an image from Safari? Have you tried un-installing and re-installing Xcode ?

Comment: @Guillaume No - no reason. It's just what I have from the last time it was updated.  Also, I'm not really an Xcode user - I develop with Titanium.  How can I go about checking the console when attempting to save an image from Safari.

Comment: Launch the app Console, in /Applications/Utilities, and in the left sidebar, select "All Messages"

Comment: So what happens when you save an image from Safari in the simulator? Does it just not appear in the camera roll?

Comment: @NightLeopard Yes, that is what was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the tip from [Guillaume](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272342/guillaume) about my Xcode version.  After updating, the Photo Albums in the simulator started to behave again :D

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /Users/apple/Pictures/
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

visit in your simulator browser: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` , then save your images.