# What are the methods/classes I need to create an iPhone upload photo form?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

Currently I have a view with an ImageViewer and 2 buttons (Browse & Upload). I'm currently searching for methods to display the iPhone photo album once the button is pressed.

I've looked at this example here but I assume this one is the method you call when you want to upload the photo into the server.

[Objective C: How to upload image and text using HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422028/objective-c-how-to-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post)

I'd like to duplicate the functionality of a web upload form.
1. Click button to browse folders.
2. Choose photo and display in a container.
3. Click Upload to upload photo into the server.

**Update:
Found some nice tutorials that helped me start with my iPhone app photo upload form.

Using UIImagePickerController

http://iosdevelopertips.com/camera/camera-application-to-take-pictures-and-save-images-to-photo-album.html

http://trailsinthesand.com/picking-images-with-the-iphone-sdk-uiimagepickercontroller/

[Adding images to iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468879/adding-images-to-iphone-simulator)

Comment: you want to look at `UIImagePickerController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use `UIImagePickerController` class
Here is the class reference for [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

Initialize the picker controller in your button event handler method. 
Then set the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` to your current viewController 
Here is the class reference for [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate)

```
picker.delegate = self;
```

Set the `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType` of picker to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` 
`picker.UIImagePickerControllerSourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`
Then present the pickerViewController (if your target device is an iPad, present the imagePickerView in a popOver control)
Once user selects an image picker controller will automatically call its delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

You can get the selected image by accessing the value for `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` from the `NSDictionary *info`

Then you can use the image for uploading to server as mentioned in the post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422028/objective-c-how-to-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post)

These are some tutorials for UIImagePickerController
[Tutorial one](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPad_Camera_and_UIImagePickerController_Application_%28Xcode_4%29)
[Tutorial two](http://zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/)
[Tutorial three](http://mobileorchard.com/ios-advanced-programming-the-image-picker/)

Comment: i'm seeing only a blank view with 2 blue horizontal bars on top. `UIImagePickerController *imgP = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 imgP.delegate = self;
 imgP.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
 [self.view addSubview:imgP.view];
 [imgP release];`

Comment: i'm adding it programmatically in a uiviewcontroller at loadView

Comment: ok fixed it hehe, i didnt need to create a new view for it. just called `[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];` instead. :)

Comment: Good to here that, I had mentioned that you have to present a pickerView ([self presentModelView...)

Answer (score 0):

for getting images from iPhone library you have to use `UIImagePickerController`.

```
m_imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
m_imagePickerController.delegate = self;
m_imagePickerController.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

hope this will help you