# Adding image to iPhone simulator cause error (PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1.)

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm trying to drag and drop image to my iPhone simulator. I found to do it this way here on SO [Adding images or videos to iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468879/adding-images-or-videos-to-iphone-simulator) . However when I tried to drag and drop simple png or jpeg image I get an error

```
operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1.)
```

I know that the solution in the answer is like 9 years old and I haven't found any latest solution so does something changed?

My iOS simulator version is

Version 11.5 (921.9.1)
SimulatorKit 581.9.1
CoreSimulator 704.12.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move your files into the `Documents` folder and then drag them into the simulator.

This will trigger the simulator to ask for permissions to access your files. Having them inside the `Downloads` folder, will not.

Answer (score 3):

Dragging photos into the Documents folder didn't work for me. I had to drag them into the Library/Developer folder and then drag them into the simulator to avoid this error.